# How can i optimize this code? Maybe though a list comporehension?

Tags: python, list, optimization, time, list-comprehension

I need to accelerate this code:

The first which i think i can do is to modify the way to obtain a list, thats the part i write in **BOLD**.

¿Some ideas? I try to do it with List comprehension but always give me the error of referenced before assignment.

```
def transform(A, x):
    
    from math import factorial
    
    def comb(i,x):
        return factorial(i)/(factorial(x)*factorial(i-x))

    lis = []

    # --- FROM HERE ---
    for i in A:
        suma = 0
        for j in range(x,i+1):
            suma += comb(j,x)
        lis.append(suma)
    # --- TO HERE ---

    return lis
    
    res = lis[0]  
    
    for i in lis[1:]:
        res = int(res) ^ int(i)
                                        
    return res
```

Thanks

Comment: Changing the way you loop is not likely to make a huge diifference. If you need to speed it up, find a better algorithm.

Comment: If you're calling factorial frequently, memoize it.

Comment: List comprehension typically makes your code easier to read.  If your problem is speed, you need a better algorithm.   I'd start by adding `@cached` in front of `def comb()`.

Comment: It's worth noting, `int(res) ^ int(i)` is *not* raising `res` to the power of `i` -- if you want power, either use `math.pow` or `int(res) ** int(i)`

Comment: add decorator  `@lru_cache` on comb to memorize results

Comment: Why are there three `return`s when only two `def`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to actually answer your specific question, though as mentioned by everyone above, it will almost certainly not improve your running speed.  You have:

```
    suma = 0
    for j in range(x,i+1):
       suma += comb(j,x)
```

This can be turned into a single sum:

```
    suma = sum(comb(j, x) for j in range(x, i + 1))
```

Your outer loop is:

```
lis = []
for i in A:
    suma = sum(....) # See code above
    lis.append(suma)
```

which can be turned into the following list comprehension:

```
lis = [sum(....) for i in A]
```